Aligning divider element centrally with the repeated elements around it
I need to create a section like this:

Here's what I have already tried:


.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.step {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.divider {
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
  border-radius: .2rem;
  height: 2px;
  width: 3rem;
  margin-top: 1.2rem;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: {
    left: $spacing--22;
    right: $spacing--22;
  }
}
<div class="container">
  <div v-for="(step, index) in steps" :key="index" class="step">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="icon">
        // ICON CONTENT
      </div>
      <h3 class="title">
        // TITLE CONTENT
      </h3>
      <p class="description">
        // DESCRIPTION CONTENT
      </p>
    </div>
    <div v-if="index + 1 < steps.length" class="step-process__divider" />
  </div>
</div>



The problem is that the divider doesn't look like it's always centered between the two step elements.
Is there a better way to achieve this?

I'd prefer you to use CSS-pseudo elements and CSS-selectors, specifically, :not, first-child, last-child, before and after.
You can use the :not selector to get the child elements that are not first or last, i.e., anything between them, then add lines before and after the component.
See this working example:


.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.step {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

.divider {
  background-color: #d9d9d9;
  border-radius: .2rem;
  height: 2px;
  width: 3rem;
  margin-top: 1.2rem;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  margin: {
    left: $spacing--22;
    right: $spacing--22;
  }
}

.custom-class:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.custom-class:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)::before {
  content: '—';
}

.custom-class:not(:first-child):not(:last-child)::after {
  content: '—';
}
<div class="container">
  <div v-for="(step, index) in steps" :key="index" class="step">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="custom-class icon">
        ICON CONTENT
      </div>
      <h3 class="custom-class title">
        TITLE CONTENT
      </h3>
      <p class="custom-class description">
        DESCRIPTION CONTENT
      </p>
    </div>
    <div v-if="index + 1 < steps.length" class="step-process__divider" />
  </div>
</div>



